In react app, using private route unable to navigate to protected page once after successful login
Even though my login is successful and I am getting the isAuthenticated = true, system is not redirecting to the admin component/ page in my react app. What could be the issue here, can someone please advise ? I am not getting any error.
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.1",
     node v20.14.0

//PrivateRoute.js
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ element, isAuthenticated, ...props }) => {
    return isAuthenticated ? (
      <Route {...props} element={element} />
    ) : (
      <Route path="/admin" element={<Navigate to="/login" />} />
    );
};

export default PrivateRoute;

//index.js:
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./client/components/Home";
import About from "./client/components/About";
import Login from "./client/components/Login";
import Admin from "./client/components/Admin";

import './index.css';

const App = () => {

  const [isAuthenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  console.log("What is coming here:::"+isAuthenticated)
  // getting isAuthenticated = true 

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route
          path="/login"
          element={<Login setAuthenticated={setAuthenticated} />}
        />
       {isAuthenticated ? (
          <Route path="/admin" element={<Admin />} />
        ) : (
          <Route path="/admin" element={<Navigate to="/login" />} />
        )}
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

const root = document.getElementById('root');
const rootElement = (
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
const rootContainer = createRoot(root);
rootContainer.render(rootElement);

// Login.js
import React, { useState} from 'react';

const Login = ({ setAuthenticated  }) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  
    const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
      setEmail(e.target.value);
    };
  
    const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
      setPassword(e.target.value);
    };
  
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Here you can handle form submission, like sending a request to your backend
      console.log('Email:', email);
      console.log('Password:', password);

      // Reset form fields after submission
      setEmail('');
      setPassword('');
      // Reset form fields after submission
      if (email === 'admin@signal.com' && password === 'Admin1234') {
        console.log('Login successful');
        setAuthenticated(true); // Set loggedIn to true upon successful login
        
      } else {
        console.log('Login failed');
      }
      
    };
  
    return (
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center h-screen">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4">
          <div className="mb-4">
            <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="email">
              Email
            </label>
            <input
              className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              id="email"
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              value={email}
              onChange={handleEmailChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="mb-6">
            <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="password">
              Password
            </label>
            <input
              className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              id="password"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              value={password}
              onChange={handlePasswordChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
            <button
              className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              type="submit"
            >
              Sign In
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default Login;

CodeSandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nice-einstein-tk7r9j?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js

I see nothing in the code you shared here that attempts to navigate to "/admin". Is this a complete [mcve]? Side note, your PrivateRoute implementation is incorrect, but since you aren't using/rendering it I guess it's not throwing any error either for you see that it is incorrect.

When you are navigating by changing the url manually. All states will reset. You should store this information in sessionStorage or localStorage

Not sure, When I login successfully, i am getting the isAuthenticated = true , so not sure why that is not navigating to /admin page .

In login file
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = ({ setAuthenticated }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = () => {
  
    setAuthenticated(true);
    navigate('/admin'); // add this
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Login Page</h2>
      <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;



if you can provide a code sandbox, much appreciated,

Thank you Dileepa, do we actually need this PrivateRoute component, now it is work without that too.. Is this implementation is okie ?

in your case, you are only protecting a single route. so the private route componenet wont need, if you are using more private routes, with role based access you can implement that. please refer to this article about private routes.  https://dev.to/iamandrewluca/private-route-in-react-router-v6-lg5 good one.

Thank you, I have created a codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nice-einstein-tk7r9j?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js

is this a private sandbox

Sorry I didn't realize it, can you check if you can access now , https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nice-einstein-tk7r9j?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js

still not working

I have moved to public now:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nice-einstein-tk7r9j?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js

Now are you planning to implement private route componenet or another functionality

I would like to have authentication enabled using PrivateRoutes. Not sure what mistake I have done in the above PrivateRoute.js component
